# html icon with css class definition not found

Tags: html, css, ionicons

When debug a webpage, a icon show on page but do not find the class definition! for example, below code use a class "icon icon-md ion-md-power", which libray should include to use this icon. any tutorial is welcome since I am a newbie for web programming!

```
<ion-icon name="md-power" role="img" class="icon icon-md ion-md-power" aria-label="power"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: icon does not appear  jsfiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/sj12qhy3/

Comment: you need to link to the ressource needed  and use icon name avalaible : https://jsfiddle.net/pbhvgq0a/  You can start from here and check out usage https://ionicons.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ionicons not use CSS to display icon. ionicon have svg icons and get svg content by JavaScript based on `ion-icon`'s attributes. You can learn about the Shadow DOM technology that ionicon uses to display icons in an [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM).

> [icon.tsx](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/blob/master/src/components/icon/icon.tsx#L119), [utils.ts#getUrl()](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/blob/master/src/components/icon/utils.ts#L26)
>
> ```js
>   loadIcon() {
>     if (Build.isBrowser && this.isVisible) {
>       const url = getUrl(this); // <-- get URL of SVG icon! getUrl() declare at utils.ts.
>       if (url) {
>         if (ioniconContent.has(url)) {
>           this.svgContent = ioniconContent.get(url);
>         } else {
>           getSvgContent(url).then(() => this.svgContent = ioniconContent.get(url));
>         }
>       }
>     }
> ```